# Nuxt - Cannot call useContext() inside watch() callback

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I'm using [`@nuxtjs/composition-api`](https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/) version 0.33.1 with Nuxt 2, and my component looks like this:

```js
import { defineComponent, useContext, useRoute, watch } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';

export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    const route = useRoute();

    // Other code...

    watch(() => route.value.query, () => {
      const { $axios } = useContext();
    });

    // Other code...
  }
});
```

As you can see, I'm trying to do something when the `route.value.query` changes. However, this gives me the error:

```
Error: This must be called within a setup function.
    at useContext (index.mjs?9a99:220:1)
    at eval (search.vue?9447:34:1)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.common.dev.js?4650:3634:1)
    at call (vue.common.dev.js?4650:3271:1)
    at watcher.run (vue.common.dev.js?4650:3375:1)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.common.dev.js?4650:3140:1)
    at Array.eval (vue.common.dev.js?4650:3760:1)
    at flushCallbacks (vue.common.dev.js?4650:3682:1)
```

Did I miss something? How can I call `useContext()` inside the callback of `watch()`? Or is it not possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [confirmed](https://github.com/nuxt-community/composition-api/issues/736) by the developer of the package, it is not possible to have `useContext()` in the watcher callback.

The workaround is to call `useContext()` first, then use its returned values in the callback.

```
import { defineComponent, useContext, useRoute, watch } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';
export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    const route = useRoute();
    // Other code...

    const { $axios } = useContext();
    watch(() => route.value.query, () => {
      // use $axios here
    });
    // Other code...
  }
});
```